# Calling a javascript function through micro template

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the micro template ([Micro Template](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating)) in my project. Below is the sample

```
<script type="text/html" id="user_tmpl">
  <% for ( var i = 0; i < users.length; i++ ) { %>
    <li><a href="<%=users[i].url%>"><%=users[i].name%></a></li>
  <% } %>
</script>
```

Is it possible to call a javascript function say a simple function like this:

```
function SubstringText(input,length) {
    return input.substring(1, length);
}
```

on users[i].name property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call it directly in the script, for example:

```
<script type="text/html" id="user_tmpl">
  <% for ( var i = 0; i < users.length; i++ ) { %>
    <li><a href="<%=users[i].url%>"><%=SubstringText(users[i].name, 5)%></a></li>
  <% } %>
</script>
```

I'm not sure what `length` you want here, just replace `5` with whatever that is in the example above.